# Finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of an ODE in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Let's say one is given the ODE y'' + ay = 0 with boundary conditions y'(0) = 0 and y'(1) = 0. How would one use Mathematica to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions? What if one is given a more general ODE, let's say y'' + (y^2 - 1/2)y = 0 with the same boundary conditions?

---

This question has been answered by Simon's comment below.

Comment: your second example has two variables but only one equation: - do you mean y^2?

Comment: Does your first example have any nontrivial eigenfunctions?

Comment: Yes, for the first example, the eigenvalues should be n^{2}\pi^{2}, n = 0, 1, 2,... with eigenfunctions \cos(\sqrt{a}x) (if I haven't computed this by hand incorrectly).

Comment: Sorry, that was just me being dense. So you're considering the operator $\partial_x^2$ with eigenvalue $a$. Try running `Reduce[y'[0]==0&&y'[1]==0&&a!=0&&(C[1]!=0||C[2]!=0)/.DSolve[y''[x]+ a^2 y[x]==0,y,x],a]//FullSimplify`. As for the second case, it's not a linear operator acting on $y$... so eigenvalues aren't really appropriate...

Comment: To the individual(s) who voted to close, this is a valid question with regards to the Mathematica programming language and environment. Hence, it is not off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DSolve` only gives solutions for "generic" parameters, which is why

```
DSolve[y''[x] + a^2 y[x] == 0 && y'[0] == 0 && y'[1] == 0, y, x]
```

only returns the trivial `{{y -> Function[{x}, 0]}}`.

If you're considering $-a^2$ to be an eigenvalue of the second derivative operator with the 0 velocity boundary conditions, first solve

```
In[1]:= sol = DSolve[y''[x] + a^2 y[x] == 0, y, x]
Out[1]= {{y -> Function[{x}, C[1] Cos[a x] + C[2] Sin[a x]]}}
```

then enforce the boundary conditions using `Reduce`
(where, to simplify the result, I've also assumed that `a != 0` 
and that `sol` is not trivial)

```
In[2]:= Reduce[y'[0] == 0 && y'[1] == 0 && 
               a != 0 && (C[1] != 0 || C[2] != 0) /. sol, 
               a] // FullSimplify

Out[2]= Element[C[3], Integers] && C[2] == 0 && C[1] != 0 && 
        ((a == 2*Pi*C[3] && a != 0) || Pi + 2*Pi*C[3] == a)
```

which says that the eigenvectors are proportional to $\cos(a x)$ for $a = 2 n \pi$ or $a = (2 n + 1) \pi$ with $n$ an integer.

---

As for the second equation in your question, it only makes sense to talk about eigenvectors for linear operators. For nonlinear differential equations, eigenvectors are useful for examining the linearized behaviour around critical points.